# Is there a letter from Bohr about the 1950 Nobel prize?

Tags: history, physics, history-of-science

[César Lattes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Lattes) had some important participation in the discovery of the the [pi meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion#History), but the Nobel prize was awarded to [Cecil Powell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecil_Powell) alone.

There are claims that Niels Bohr left a letter explaining why Lattes wasn't awarded the Nobel Prize. [One source: The Oxford Companion to the History of Modern Science](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=abqjP-_KfzkC&pg=PA452&lpg=PA452&dq=bohr+lattes+letter&source=bl&ots=C_2P1WZ5zJ&sig=Cs_RGSK0uHRivKHju3QwRyCXDDo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xdvrUoPhDsbLsQTok4HgCA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=bohr%20lattes%20letter&f=false):

> Powell received the Nobel Prize of 1950 for the discovery, an award that Latin Americans feel should have gone to Lattes. A letter from Niels Bohr, to be opened in 2012, supposedly explains Lattes's exclusion.

Is there any letter from Niels Bohr about this subject?

Comment: Related: [2012 embargo may have been broken in 2002](http://www.nba.nbi.dk/papers/introduction.htm)

Comment: @Oddthinking That link is broken.

Comment: @JAB: I am afraid I haven't got a replacement link.

Answer (score 4):

There's a paper in trying to answer this question [On the “Missing Letter” to Lattes and the Nobel Prize in Physics](http://revistas.cbpf.br/index.php/CS/article/download/120/100), but the existence of this letter is still unproved.

> We can also conclude that there is no longer controversy regarding
>   Bohr and Lattes, at least according to the Bohr Archives, but from the
>   evidences exposed, the possibility of a missing letter still remains.
>   . .